# PHP / MySQL - Construct a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a little trouble constructing a query.

I have a table with 3 columns.

id - day - pageviews

What i basically want to do is get 8 id's from the table where the pageviews are the highest from the last 60 days.

The day column is a datetime mysql type.

Any help would be great, im having a little trouble figuring this one out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same as TuteC posted, but you'll need a group by to get what you need...

```
SELECT id, SUM(pageviews) totalViews
FROM table
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) <= day
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY totalViews DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Why do you need SUM()? If pageviews is an integer, you only need to select it.
And why the GROUP BY? Regards.

Comment: @TuteC - because as far as I understand form the table - he's going to have one row per day. Without a SUM - it would get top daily visited pages, which might be the same page every day, not 8 pages that were visited the most during the last 40 days.

Comment: You are right, Serge, thank you. And what about the GROUP BY statement? Regards.

Comment: @TuteC - SUM without group by would produce only one row, as it will just get as sum of all the values int he column. Adding group by will make sure that sum is done for every id, instead of "grand total"

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) <= day
ORDER BY pageviews DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sixtyDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-60 days'));

$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM table_name
        WHERE day >= '$sixtyDaysAgo 00:00:00'
        ORDER BY pageviews DESC
        LIMIT 8";
```

If each row is a number of pageviews for that day, and you're looking for the highest total sum of 60 days' worth, then you'll need to total them all and then grab the top 8 from among those totals, like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM (
            SELECT id, SUM(pageviews) AS total_pageviews
            FROM table_name
            WHERE day >= '$sixtyDaysAgo 00:00:00'
            GROUP BY id
        ) AS subselect
        ORDER BY total_pageviews DESC
        LIMIT 8";
```